# How do i make my program recognized by Windows Protector and AntiViruses?

Tags: python, security, exe

I am trying to make a program, but when I turn it into .exe it's unrecognized by windows protector. And when I tried to run it in virtual box (virtual pc) AVG Antivirus detects it as a rare file, and it deleted it when I ran the program, how do I make it secure? I used "auto py to exe" to turn python codes to exe.

Auto py to exe uses pyinstaller to convert it, It uses GUI so it's much easier to use. It also shows the command of the pyinstaller.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your python to exe convertor has bad reputation. Try a popular one `pyinstaller`, using next steps:

1. Install pyinstaller through `python -m pip install pyinstaller`.
2. Package your python script e.g. `example.py` through `pyinstaller --onefile --noupx example.py`, result will be in file `dist/example.exe`.